# change src + image title

Tags: javascript, image, title, src

I am changing the img src to create a sort of slideshow, i want the text under my photos to change depending on the src, i tried with replacewith() but it is not working, someone can help? that would be rrreeeeaaaly nice!

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 


    var image_tracker='36'

function slide()
{   


    var image = document.getElementById('intro');

        if(image_tracker==='36')       
        {   
            image.src='galerie/37l.jpg';
            image_tracker='37'; 

        }

        else if(image_tracker=='37'){
            image.src='galerie/38l.jpg';
            image_tracker='38';

        }
        else if(image_tracker==='38'){
            image.src='galerie/39l.jpg';
            image_tracker='39';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='39'){
            image.src='galerie/40l.jpg';
            image_tracker='40';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='40'){
            image.src='galerie/41l.jpg';
            image_tracker='41';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='41'){
            image.src='galerie/42l.jpg';
            image_tracker='42';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='42'){
            image.src='galerie/43l.jpg';
            image_tracker='43';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='43'){
            image.src='galerie/44l.jpg';
            image_tracker='44';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='44'){
            image.src='galerie/45l.jpg';
            image_tracker='45';
        }
        else if(image_tracker==='45'){
            image.src='galerie/46l.jpg';
            image_tracker='46';
        }

        else{
            image.src==='galerie/backintroju.jpg';
            image_tracker='36';
        }}

  var b = window.setInterval('slide()',1500);

  </script>
```

```html
        <body>


        <div id='photos'><img src='galerie/backintroju.jpg'id='intro'class='responsivegal'/></div>

        <div id='infosphotos' class='t37'>08:55am&nbsp; July&nbsp; 25 &nbsp;2015, &nbsp; <b id='urk'>Urk </b>&nbsp; (The Netherlands)</div>

        <div id='boutondroite'> <a href='l37.html'><img src='image1/droite.png'class='responsivebouton'/></a> </div>



        <div id='fermer'><a href='photos.html'><img src='image1/fermer3.png'class='responsivebouton'/></a></div>
          </body>
```

Comment: Firstly - could you provide code with your previous attempt and secondly, where is this text? What element does it reside within?

Comment: ok the text under the photos is <div id='infosphotos' class='t37'> in the body, and my previous attempt was something like that, trying to change the text directly in the if statement , for example :                           if(image_tracker==='36')      
        {  
            image.src='galerie/37l.jpg';
            image_tracker='37';
            $(document.getElementById('infosphotos')).replaceWith('14:36pm &nbsp;July&nbsp; 29&nbsp; 2015, &nbsp; Dwingeloo &nbsp; (The Netherlands)')
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the contents of any element with the `innerHTML` property.

```
<div id="foo">
    First this text
</div>
```

This will render just the line 'First this text', though with this script

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "Now this text";
</script>
```

the line 'Now this text' will be rendered. Just decide when you execute the line of code.

Comment: and how can i execute this line of code when the img src is changing, for exemple: set text ''bleble'  when image.src='galerie/37l.jpg'; ? Can i decide it directly inside my function slide() ?

Comment: last question though, how can innerhtml recognize the &nbsp;

Comment: Javscript doesn't understand `&nbsp`, so use the unicode sequence for it: `\u00A0`.

Comment: Don't forget to close or delete your question if you do not need further help.

Comment: You can click the checkmark next to my answer, and it will mark the question as closed using my answer as the solution. You can also choose to just delete your question. There's a "delete" anchor below your question (grayish colour). It should be next to the "edit" button.